# Changing BottomNavigationView's Icon Size

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

I have been experimenting with the new BottomNavigationView and trying to customise it.

So far I have managed to change the height and margins by using the below:

```
<dimen name="design_bottom_navigation_height" tools:override="true">75dp</dimen>
<dimen name="design_bottom_navigation_margin" tools:override="true">5dp</dimen>
```

I want to increase the size of the icons.

How can this be done?

Compile Version: com.android.support:design:25.0.1

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42318954/how-to-increase-bottom-navigation-view-height-along-with-its-icon-and-text-sizes/47030341#47030341

Answer (score 57, accepted):

**Late but Latest**

Use `implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'` Design Support Library.

There is an property to change Icon Size:

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    app:itemIconSize="@dimen/_26sdp">
    ....
    ....
</android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView>
```

**Programmatically:**

```
dashboardNavigation.setItemIconSize(24);
```

### UPDATE:

If you are using a material library then it will be the same. Just change the package name as below.

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
```

**XML:**

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
                app:itemIconSize="@dimen/_26sdp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

**Programmatically** - Same as above.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you if it is possible to change it programmatically?

Comment: how to change text size in BottomNavigationView

Answer (score 31):

The icon size is hardcoded to 24dp in the item layout (see [design_bottom_navigation_item.xml](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/design/res/layout/design_bottom_navigation_item.xml)) and can be changed programmatically:

```
BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) configurationActivity.findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation_view);
BottomNavigationMenuView menuView = (BottomNavigationMenuView) bottomNavigationView.getChildAt(0);
for (int i = 0; i < menuView.getChildCount(); i++) {
    final View iconView = menuView.getChildAt(i).findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.icon);
    final ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = iconView.getLayoutParams();
    final DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    layoutParams.height = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 32, displayMetrics);
    layoutParams.width = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 32, displayMetrics);
    iconView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
}
```

Comment: I can't believe they hard code the size and didn't use style attributes to set the value which can bring more flexibility for developers...

Comment: I love you bro, you saved my day!

Comment: How to get the bottomNavigationView on kotlin, cause I get NPE on: val bottomNavigationView = bottom_navigation_view

Comment: Why do we need to call bottomNavigationView.getChildAt(0) ? 
Or what's the difference between BottomNaviagationView and BottomNavigationMenuView ?

Comment: what will be resource name for androidx package

Comment: @ozmank for androidx use this id - `andcom.google.android.material.R.id.ico`

Comment: Since material:1.4.0 the id to use now is : com.google.android.material.R.id.navigation_bar_item_icon_view

Answer (score 4):

For **androidx** use this id for icons
`andcom.google.android.material.R.id.icon`

The full code:

```
BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) configurationActivity.findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation_view);
BottomNavigationMenuView menuView = (BottomNavigationMenuView) bottomNavigationView.getChildAt(0);
for (int i = 0; i < menuView.getChildCount(); i++) {
    final View iconView = menuView.getChildAt(i).findViewById(com.google.android.material.R.id.icon);
    final ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = iconView.getLayoutParams();
    final DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    layoutParams.height = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 32, displayMetrics);
    layoutParams.width = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 32, displayMetrics);
    iconView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
}
```

Comment: Since material:1.4.0 the id to use now is : com.google.android.material.R.id.navigation_bar_item_icon_view

Answer (score 3):

This worked perfectly for me with AndroidX
Your XML layout

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    style="@style/DA_Bottom_Nav"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    app:itemIconSize="50dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/nav_menu"/>
```

Res/values/dimens.xml

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <dimen name="design_bottom_navigation_height" tools:override="true">80dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to change one of your `BottomNavigationView`'s icon's size, here is a quick and easy solution.

Let's say, you've 5 items on your `BottomNavigationView` and you want to change the middle icon size:

```
BottomNavigationMenuView menuView = (BottomNavigationMenuView)
            mainBinding.bottomNavView.getChildAt(0);
// Here the index: 2 at 'getChildAt(2)' means the middle icon
BottomNavigationItemView navigationItemView = (BottomNavigationItemView) menuView.getChildAt(2);

final DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
            
navigationItemView.setIconSize((int)
            TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 40,
                    displayMetrics));
```

Now you have it changed ;)

Comment: Seems hacky but not the best idea, or scalable. When you do that: "NavigationBarItemView.setIconSize can only be called from within the same library group (groupId=com.google.android.material)"

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin extension, it works with material:1.4.0

```
fun BottomNavigationView.resizeIcon(indexIcon:Int, sizeDp:Float){
    val menuView = getChildAt(0) as BottomNavigationMenuView
    val iconView = menuView.getChildAt(indexIcon).findViewById<View>(com.google.android.material.R.id.navigation_bar_item_icon_view)
    val layoutParams = iconView.layoutParams
    val displayMetrics = resources.displayMetrics
    val newSize = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, sizeDp, displayMetrics).toInt()
    layoutParams.height =newSize
    layoutParams.width = newSize
    val fl = FrameLayout.LayoutParams(newSize,newSize, Gravity.CENTER)
    iconView.layoutParams = fl
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For **androidx** `com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0`

```
BottomNavigationMenuView menuView = (BottomNavigationMenuView) navigationView.getChildAt(0);
BottomNavigationItemView itemView = (BottomNavigationItemView) menuView.getChildAt(2); // icon index

final View iconView = itemView.findViewById(com.google.android.material.R.id.navigation_bar_item_icon_view);
final DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
iconView.getLayoutParams().width = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 38, displayMetrics);
iconView.getLayoutParams().height = MATCH_PARENT;

final View iconContainerView = itemView.findViewById(com.google.android.material.R.id.navigation_bar_item_icon_container);
iconContainerView.getLayoutParams().width = MATCH_PARENT;
iconContainerView.getLayoutParams().height = MATCH_PARENT;
```

[image]