# How to add indicator on a taller-than-default BottomNavigationView?

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

### Background

I'm trying to have a bit larger BottomNavigationView (height is a bit bigger), while also making each item icon have a top indicator that it's selected.

Something like that, but with larger height:

[image]

It's a bit hard to see it on the screenshot, but the indicator is shown at the very top of the BottomNavigationView's item, right below the BottomNavigationView's shadow.

### The problem

When I set a larger height, I get each item still take smaller height, so the indicator doesn't look at the top:

[image]

Not only that, but because I used `itemBackground` to set the background of each item to have the indicator, it now doesn't have the background used for the clicking effect.

### What I've found

About the height, I've found [**this question on StackOverflow**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42318954/878126), of changing the height. The only solution there is to override the library's dimensions. In this case, it's only this:

```
<dimen name="design_bottom_navigation_height" tools:override="true">...</dimen>
```

However, this only solves the issue of putting the indicator at the top.

Plus, it looks like a dirty solution, to set the dimension forcefully for the library, and as I wrote, because I used `itemBackground` , it doesn't have the normal clicking effect anymore.

Here's the relevant code, modified just a bit from the wizard of Android Studio for making "Bottom Navigation Activity". The rest is the same as there :

**activity_main.xml**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/container" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/message" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" android:text="@string/title_home"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view" android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/tabs_height" android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp" android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground" app:itemBackground="@drawable/activity_main__tab_background"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled" app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**dimens.xml**

```
<dimen name="tabs_height">64dp</dimen>
<dimen name="design_bottom_navigation_height" tools:override="true">@dimen/tabs_height</dimen>
```

**activity_main__tab_background.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true">
        <layer-list>
            <item android:gravity="top">
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <size android:height="2dp"/>
                    <solid android:color="#07a5ea"/>
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
</selector>
```

### The question

How can I have the indicator at the top, while having a larger BottomNavigationView and without losing the clicking effect?

Comment: Tried the same thing...running as expected with click events, indicator at top and custom height. Is there anything I misunderstood about question?

Comment: You see clicking effect ? And you don't see extra space? How come? See attached project here: https://ufile.io/vuyygja9 . Please try it out. Set an even larger height than what I've set. Try to click the items too.

Comment: I just removed comment from dimens file...for this line <dimen name="design_bottom_navigation_height" tools:override="true">@dimen/tabs_height</dimen> and it is working...

Comment: @NaitikSoni I don't understand. What is working?

Comment: Indicator at top, with click event and custom height. all things are pretty working.

Comment: @NaitikSoni Can you please share the code and/or project? What exactly did you do? Are the sure the indicator is indeed at the top, without spacing between the item and the shadow of the BottomNavigationView, as I've shown on the screenshot? Try setting it to have even larger height than what I've set (example: 100dp), and see if it's at the top or has space.

Comment: Tried with 120dp. [see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3TIq.jpg)

Comment: How odd. Can you please share what you did? Maybe upload the project to the same website I have?

Comment: Can I know the version of a device you are checking on?? Mine is android 9.

Comment: I've tested on Galaxy Note 8 with Android 8.0. I now tried to have only `design_bottom_navigation_height` set, and there is still no clicking effect.

Comment: So you can't click on any tab/icon? and the value of textview is not changing...Is that so?

Comment: I didn't say I can't click. I said there is no clicking effect. There is no ripple, for example. If I remove the `app:itemBackground` part, there is a clicking effect. Also, as for the height of the `BottomNavigationView`, as I wrote, I wish to avoid using the hack/workaround I've mentioned if possible (of `design_bottom_navigation_height `) . If there is a more reliable way to do it, it would be better.

Comment: Oh...sorry. there is where I misunderstood. Haven't thought of ripple effect. But still I am trying now.

Comment: Please also try to avoid `design_bottom_navigation_height` . I mentioned it only because that's what I've found, and I think that if there is a better alternative, it's worth use it instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the best solution is to change the margin of the item imageView from kotlin code on runtime
here is the code

```
private fun navigationImagesMargin(view: View) {
        if (view is ViewGroup) {
            for (i in 0 until view.childCount) {
                val child = view.getChildAt(i)
                navigationImagesMargin(child)
            }
        } else if (view is ImageView) {
            val param = view.layoutParams as ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams
            param.topMargin = convertDpToPx(14)
            view.layoutParams = param
        } 
    }
fun convertDpToPx(dp: Int): Int {
    return Math.round(dp * (resources.displayMetrics.xdpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT))
}
```

in the onCreate function call `navigationImagesMargin` function on the BottomNavigation View

```
navigationImagesMargin(binding.spBottomNavigation)
```

but this solution requires to recall `navigationImagesMargin` function everytime the view revalidated i.e. in the onItemClick listener here is the code for that

```
 binding.spBottomNavigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener { it->
            binding.spBottomNavigation.post {
                navigationImagesMargin(binding.spBottomNavigation)
            }
            true
        }
```

in that way the images will stay where you aimed them to be on first launch

this is a link for tiny repo that include the full code
https://github.com/abdulmalekDery/BottomNavigationControl

Comment: Sorry but I forgot about this. If you have a tiny Github sample to show me, I can test it and mark it as answered.

Comment: ok..gonna send you link to a project asap

Comment: sorry for delay I've edited the answer to include a link for a tiny git repo https://github.com/abdulmalekDery/BottomNavigationControl

Comment: Seems to work, but it has an issue that it adds the fragments so they get merged (text on top of text), and the repository doesn't put a link to here. Is the code you wrote here the only thing that's needed?

Comment: actually..I'm using the navigation component library in my original project..I've created that repo just to demonstrate the solution for your question....I can update the repo to include the library if you wish..just let me know if you want that

Comment: Yes please. Why does it have the issue though? Did you add fragment on top of fragment, and had them transparent, or something?

Comment: Hi @android developer I've added the navigation component support you can check it out... don't forget to mark my answer as accepted answer if so.. Welcome any time my friend!

Comment: Seems to work fine now, but you didn't add a link to here on the repository's "README.md" file :  https://github.com/abdulmalekDery/BottomNavigationControl . The description is empty.

Comment: Anyway I mark it as the answer, but please put a link on the repository to here.

Comment: thanks...I've added the link of the question and answer to README.md