# BottomNavigationView - why is there not enough space for the badge Drawable?

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview, material-components-android

I use a `BottomNavigationView` from the material library: `const val material = "com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0-rc01"`

and set/update a badge on it using the following binding:

```
@BindingAdapter("cartCount")
fun BottomNavigationView.updateCartCount(count: Int) {
    getOrCreateBadge(R.id.action_cart).apply {
        isVisible = count > 0
        if (isVisible) number = count
    }
}
```

Here's the View in XML (inside a `ConstraintLayout`)

```
    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_nav"
        cartCount="@{viewModel.cartCount}"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:elevation="8dp"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/bottom_nav_item_color"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/bottom_nav_item_color"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_bottom_nav" />
```

My issue is that there seems to be not enough space for the badge:

[image: cart unselected]

Which is more noticeable when the item is selected:

[image: cart selected]

What I have tried to fix the issue, to no avail:

- using a different material version, trying different versions (starting with 1.3.0)
- increasing the height of the `BottomNavigationView`, here I set it to a ridiculous 100dp:

[image]

- changing the size of the icons
- setting `bottom_navigation_notification_padding` and some other attrs from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42318954/how-to-increase-bottom-navigation-view-height-along-with-its-icon-and-text-sizes?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- looking for some info in the material [release notes](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/releases)

I was unable to find any "known issue" related to my problem. What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In com.google.android.material:material v1.3.0 and above you can use `setVerticalOffset` or `setHorizontalOffset`  of `BadgeDrawable` to move the Badge vertically or horizontally with a specific amount in pixels.

[setVerticalOffset(int px)](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/badge/BadgeDrawable#setVerticalOffset(int))

> Sets how much (in pixels) to vertically move this badge towards the
> center of its anchor.

[setHorizontalOffset(int px)](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/badge/BadgeDrawable#setHorizontalOffset(int))

> Sets how much (in pixels) to horizontally move this badge towards the
> center of its anchor.

Example:

```
val menuItemId: Int = bottomNavigation.getMenu().getItem(1).getItemId()
val badge: BadgeDrawable = bottomNavigation.getOrCreateBadge(menuItemId)
badge.setVisible(true)
badge.setNumber(4)
badge.setVerticalOffset(10) //value in pix
badge.setHorizontalOffset(-10) //value in pix
```

**Result with and without offset:**

[image: no_offset]
[image: with_offset]

Comment: I wasn't aware of this API, thanks for the hint! Applying a small offset did fix the issue.