# Different look/style for specific item on BottomNavigationMenu

Tags: android, user-interface, xamarin, xamarin.android, navigation

I am currently building a Xamarin Android application, and I am trying to customize the BottomNavigationView.

I would like to be able to change the style of a specific menu item in the BottomNavigationView from the following:

[image: Current Bottom Navigation View]

To this style:

[image: Desired Navigation View]

I have had a look at the following question: [Different look/style for specific menu item on ActionBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8598015/different-look-style-for-specific-menu-item-on-actionbar) but it seems more targeted towards the action bar rather then the bottom navigation.

I'm guessing this would either need a custom control implemented or use of reflection to achieve the desired result? Any third-party libraries that implement this sort of functionality, aren't particularly helpful as majority of them are written for native android and not xamarin.

Any help in either Xamarin C# or Native Java (that I could convert) would be great thanks.

Currently I tried setting a custom action layout on the menu item programmatically:

```
var nav = FindViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.Id.bottom_navigation);

var result = nav.Menu.GetItem(2);

result.SetTitle(null);
result.SetIcon(null);

var image = new ImageButton(this);

image.SetImageDrawable(GetDrawable(R.Drawable.ic_action_grade));
image.SetColorFilter(Android.Graphics.Color.Black);

result.SetActionView(image);
```

And by specifying a custom layout, using the menu item's `app:actionLayout` property. Source: https://www.techrepublic.com/article/pro-tip-use-a-custom-layout-to-badge-androids-action-bar-menu-items/

**view_accent_grade.axml (Action Layout)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black">

  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/ic_action_grade"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:src="@drawable/ic_action_grade" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**menu.axml** (Menu Layout)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="https://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
        android:title="@string/action_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_home" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_events"
        android:title="@string/action_events"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_event" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_car_of_the_month"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/view_accent_grade" /> <!-- Specifying App Layout here --> 

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_photos"
        android:title="@string/action_photos"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_photo" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_more"
        android:title="@string/action_more"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_more_horiz" />

</menu>
```

Comment: show me what have you done so far

Comment: @G.hakim please have a look at my updated answer

Comment: the code you are using is not giving you the desired result but what exactly is it doing so far ?

Comment: @G.hakim currently both approaches are creating the menu item, but neither are displaying the actionLayout.

Comment: you want the star to look like in the second image?

Comment: @G.hakim yes the top image is what it looks like using the standard behavior from the BottomNavigationView. The bottom image the desired effect; with the icon filling the entire bar and having a different background colour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably better off writing a custom bottom navigation view yourself instead of trying to work in the constraints of the `BottomNavigationView` control. Here is a quick example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/grey_5">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="4dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_gradient_soft" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="@dimen/spacing_medium">

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                    android:onClick="clickAction"
                    android:tint="@color/teal_600"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_apps" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_height="0dp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="@dimen/spacing_medium">

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                    android:onClick="clickAction"
                    android:tint="@color/teal_500"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_local_offer" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="clickAction"
        android:tint="@android:color/white"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/teal_500"
        app:elevation="2dp"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:rippleColor="@color/deep_orange_400"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_shopping_cart" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Result:

[image: Bottom Navigation Bar with FAB]

Otherwise you can traverse the layout and apply whatever view styling you want to `BottomNavigationView` like the following answer:

[Changing BottomNavigationView's Icon Size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41516568/changing-bottomnavigationviews-icon-size)

**EDIT:**

There's a binding of an extension library to `BottomNavigationView` that has a sample of what you're trying to do:

https://github.com/NAXAM/bottomnavigationviewex-android-binding

Comment: Thanks I will give this a try tomorrow! The bottom navigation view does seem to be incredibly limited.